# Garmin data to CSV to SHAPE on ios

Tags: qgis, gps, garmin

I'm new to working with gis software. I've always been a field guy who sends all his data in to the office for processing.
However I am trying it myself and have ran into problems pretty early on.

Basically what I want to do is take the raw data from my Garmin and convert it into a CSV which I can then import into QGIS for further processing. I was told that DNRGPS would be the program to use, but I can't seem to find any version of this or any other that will work with ios processing system.

I am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert your GPX file to CSV and then to SHP. Rather, you can import the GPX file directly into QGIS. Here is how I do it using QGIS 2.14:

```
Add Vector Layer > Choose *.gpx file > Select vector layers to add... > OK
```

At that point, you can convert the GPX features to SHP (or any of a number of formats) if you like:

```
Right-click layer > Save As... > Format: ...
```